# uncheck all items of checkboxlist select in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have this check box in my ascx file :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chk" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="1">
```

i want to have a option to select no options in list. but my checkboxlist choose first option by default.and when i uncheck it and save and load page first option is seleted.

I use this code to unselect but not working:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chk.SelectedValue))
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in chk.Items)
            {
                item.Selected = false;

            }
            chk.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

I use this code in Page_Load and Page_PreRender of my page. and chk.SelectedValue is null or empty. but first items is cheked

I use this code for bind data to checkboxlist:

```
 var it = new ListItem {Text = arr1[0], Value = arr1[1];
 chk.Items.Add(it);
```

Comment: Is the checkbox list databound or are you providing the options yourself?

Comment: Check out Tim Schmelter's answer, it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Call:

```
CheckBoxList1.ClearSelection();
```

on pageload.

Comment: FYI - This clears the selections but doesn't uncheck the checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is pointless. You are checking if no item is selected(`string.IsNullOrEmpty(chk.SelectedValue)`), then you want to unselect all.

I assume you want the opposite:

```
if (chk.SelectedIndex != -1)   // you can also use chk.SelectedValue != "", default is an empty string ("")
{
    //foreach (ListItem item in chk.Items)
    //{
    //    item.Selected = false;
    //}
    chk.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

However, the loop is redundant since `SelectedIndex = -1;` does the same in one statement.

Comment: when i debug it chk.SelectedValue="" and chk.SelectedIndex=-1 but when show in pge first option is select

Comment: @atabrizi: Where do you add the statis `ListItem`? Maybe you're adding it always instead of only `if(!IsPostBack)...`.

Comment: You could try setting the ListItem.Selected property to false before you add it to the list?

Comment: if i add it in if(!IsPostBack) when page is reload my checkboxlist has not shown

Comment: @MightyLampshade i did it but first option is selected again

Comment: @atabrizi: Why will it be invisible if you add the `IsPostback`-check? Have you disabled `ViewState`?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried the CbList.ClearSelection() method after binding?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i< chk.Items.Count; i++)
{
     chk.SetItemChecked(i, false);
}
//chk.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Please provide some context to the code. Why does it solve the problem?

Comment: Your answer is currently listed as a Low Quality Post and faces deletion. Good answers also contain an explanation/context

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solve my problem to uncheck all checked items of checkboxlist C# (which is also in the title of this post):
**uncheck all items of checkboxlist select in c #**
Thank you Lucas Baum!

```
        for (int i = 0; i < chk.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            chk.SetItemChecked(i, false);
        }
```